# How can i do two different things with 2 buttons on python(GUI)?

Tags: python, user-interface, button, onclick, assign

I would like to know how I can do 2 separate things with 2 buttons. For the moment, even if I click on my 'Hint' button, it does what the other button does. Here is my code (it is not complete yet).
        import Tkinter

```
    class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
        def __init__(self,parent):
            Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
            self.parent = parent
            self.initialize()

        def initialize(self):
            self.grid()

            self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()

            self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self)
            self.entry.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky='EW')
            self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)







            button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=" Click here plz..!",
                                    command=self.OnButtonClick)
            button.grid(column=1,row=4)

            self.entry2=Tkinter.Entry(self)

            button2 = Tkinter.Button(self,text="Hint?",
                                     command=self.OnButtonClick)
            button2.grid(column=2,row=4)

            self.resizable(True,False)
        def OnButtonClick(self):
            print"Your answer is :"
            print self.entry.get()
            if self.entry.get()== "4":
                print "GJ"
            elif self.entry.get()==" ":
                print "please enter a valid answer"
            else :
                print "Nop"

        def secndButtonClick(self):
            if self.entry2.get()=="":
                print "here is the hint"
            else:
                print"Don't write anything here"

        def OnPressEnter(self,event):
            print"Your answer is :"
            print self.entry.get()
            if self.entry.get()=="4":
                print" GJ, let me guess...You have more than 2 years old right?"
            elif self.entry.get()==" ":
                print "please enter a valid answer"
            else :
                print "Nop...you are the stupidiest person I know..."
            if self.entry2.get()==" ":
                print" Ok"
    print" 2+2=?"
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = simpleapp_tk(None)
        app.title('IQ test!')
        app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Both of your buttons commands point to self.OnButtonClick... What did you expect to happen...?  Obviously they are going to both execute that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second button's command is the same as the first one. I don't have much experience with Tkinter, but this should work

```
button2 = Tkinter.Button(self,text="Hint?",
                         command=self.secndButtonClick)
```